# How do I get sys.stdout to be monitored by GObject.io_add_watch?

Tags: python, stdout, glib, gobject

How do I get sys.stdout to be monitored by GObject.io_add_watch?

code:

```
        GObject.io_add_watch(os.fdopen(self.builder), GObject.IO_IN, self.write_to_buffer)
```

I tried to get the stdout stream of my main GTK process via os.fdopen(self.builder),
yet it raises the exception:

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

**Could you please explain how I have to properly advise GObject.io_add_watch to
watch the sys.stdout stream?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API will let you pass `sys.stdout` directly, since it's a file-like object with a `fileno()` method. It won't work right, though, because you can't read from `sys.stdout`. If you want to capture all attempts to write to stdout, you can replace it with a `pipe`:

```
import gobject
import sys
import os

def ok(stream, condition):
    s = os.fdopen(stream)
    data = s.readline()
    with open("called.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("got {} ".format(data))
    return False

def do_print():
    print "hey there"
    sys.stdout.flush()

rpipe, wpipe = os.pipe()
wpipe = os.fdopen(wpipe, "w", 0)
sys.stdout = wpipe  # Replace sys.stdout
gobject.io_add_watch(rpipe, gobject.IO_IN, ok)
gobject.idle_add(do_print)
gobject.MainLoop().run()
```

Contents of `"called.txt"` after running the script:

```
got hey there
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I hope I can adapt it to print to a Gtk Textview. How can I add a subprocess (P = multiprocessing.Process(target=function)) to be monitored. Does it need to be passed to .idle_add(), if yes how?